# Table lock in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, parallel-processing

I have a table which is getting modified by SSIS package, this ssis package is running 20+ packages in parallel and all of the packages are inserting values in same table via stored procedure and this table should have distinct records. Since all packages are running in parallel few records are getting duplicate values.

My question if I set lock on this table, and 2 process/packages try to insert into table at the same time which will get 1st priority and if table 1 get the priority 1st then would I got a error message for table 2 or it will wait till table 1 release the lock.

Implementing lock on table would have performance impact (My initial thought process, I am ready to get challenged on it).

Can anyone suggest a solution for the problem of getting duplicate records from multiple processes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your duplication issue is really caused by not locking the table.
Here are a few idea that might help:

- Change TransactionOption for all the 20+ tasks ( assuming you are using 20+ 'Execute Package Task' in one package to run other 20+ packages) from 'Supported' to 'Required';
- Instead of parallel running all tasks, put them in sequence. I would suggest to run them in sequence any way to derterminate the real cause of the duplicate.

Edit: 
- If I were you, I will to try to load all 20+ package to 20+ seperated Staging tables, and when all packages are finished, then load all staging tables to your destination table in sequence and it should be very easy to verify duplication now since all staging tables are local.

Comment: Thanks Adam for response, yes you are right i have 20+ execute package tasks in package, to you 1st point - can you please let me know how transaction option would work in this case, and to 2nd point sequential process will take lot of time to finish execution.

Comment: Actually if you lock the table, it is no big difference than running them in sequence.

Comment: That is why i am looking for some other approach, as i have to move TBs of data.